# Why is SVN over-writing some local files when synchronizing with the repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, subclipse

I am using subclipse to commit changes to SVN. Some files work, e.g. build.properties (I am developing a J2EE application) but most local changes are overwritten to match the version in the repository when I synchronize, and it says "no structural differences"?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug that was specific to Eclipse 3.5.  It was fixed a long time ago so I have to assume you are using an old version of Subclipse.  The latest is 1.6.10.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA

Comment: Thanks very much, that has fixed it! I was using the 1.0.x update, I have deleted it and got the 1.6.x update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how the local files can get over-written when you synchronise.(assuming you don't mean "synchronise" in the literal sense. You mean the  option that subclipse plugin provides.)

I follow the following protocol for committing a file change.

- Do an update of the file. This makes
  sure , your local copy is upto date.
  SVN will report a merge conflict, if
  it is not able to merge the remote
  copy to your local one. In which case
  you may do a compare with graphical
  diff output, and get the remote
  changes into your local file
  manually. Then do an update. This
  time, SVN merge of the remote file to
  your local file will succeed.
- Commit your file to the SVN repos.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it still happens. I do mean the subclipse option. When in team synchronize view, if I open the file in compare editor (or double click to do the same thing) it over-writes my local file to match the repository, saying there are no differences with the repository and that I have unsaved changes (which it has introduced by wiping my local changes).